# SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element?

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I need identify a xpath in an xml file, but the robot show me this message

> SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

Code:

```
${RESULT}=       Call Soap Method        PersonalInformation     ${list}      #METODO DEL WEB SERVICE 
#Set Global Variable        ${RESULT}
${xml_result} =          Get Last Received

${xml_unicode} =         Decode Bytes To String       ${xml_result}     UTF-8



#${obj as str}=     Convert To String     ${xml_unicode}
#Log       ${obj as str}
${root} =        Parse XML          ${xml_unicode}

${first} =               Get Element        ${root}             //*[@id="collapsible2"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2] 
Log          ${first.text}
```

Im getting the xpath in google chrome, someone know the reason for this error?

greetings

Comment: which statement is causing the error?

Comment: ${first} =               Get Element        ${root}         //[@id="collapsible2"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]

Comment: <per:age23</per:age> this element im getting Xpath in google chrome